# How can I sort mongodb data by scoring using loopback3?

Tags: mongodb, loopback

in my database, i have a collection, let's name it "cv".
I'm using a full text search of Mongodb. And I'm trying to sort my query results by mongodb 's .sort() function:

```
var cvs = await Cv.find({ where: { $text : { search : searchQuery } }, score : { $meta: "textScore" } })
                  .sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore' } });
```

but, i'm getting this error :

TypeError: Cv.find(...).sort is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

find is a repository method, not model, you have to create a repository. About the sort function I believe it does not exist in repositories, I think you could use the order filter : https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Order-filter.html.

If not, you could create a sort function in your repository or override the find function. See here : https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Repositories.html#example-custom-connector-crud-methods